# Is it possible to "trick" a function take one argument when it is expecting multiple in C++?

Tags: c++, arguments, dlib

I am looking at the "**dlib**"-library, more specifically the "**find_min**" function which is used for "**optimization**" (http://dlib.net/optimization_ex.cpp.html). The "**find_min**" function let you pass your own function as an argument, but your own function needs to take only one argument. However the function I need to pass has too many arguments (7 actually), but I need them.

So my question is this:

Is there a way to "compress" my arguments so it seems like only one, or maybe a way to change a function so it only takes one argument, but still gets all the arguments that is needed in some other smart way?

Comment: Can you edit the question to mention where exactly in `dlib` you're passing a function as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

Say you've got this function:

```
int seven_args(int a, char b, double c, int d, int e, int f, int g) {
    ...
}
```

Stuff all the arguments into a struct and make a wrapper function that takes a single struct argument:

```
struct seven_args_arguments {
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
}

int wrapper(seven_args_arguments args) {
    return seven_args(args.a, args.b, args.c, args.d, args.e, args.f, args.g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a structure that that contains all your arguments and make the function take a pointer to that structure as its sole argument.

Example:

```
Struct MyStruct {int param1; double param2; char param3;}

void MyFunction(const MyStruct* p) {......}
```

To invoke the function:

```
MyStruct params { 1, 2.5, 'c'};
MyFunction(&params);
```

Notice if all your parameters are of the same type, you could even better use a `vector` without the need to define a structure.